# External image not showing in email embedded SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

I have to send emails who's body content is generated from a SSRS report. In that report I have an external image that displays correctly if I display the report in Report Manager or if I export the report to PDF, Excel, etc. The image is hosted on Tinypic.

I render the report using HTML4.0 extension. The body is displayed correctly, but I can't see the image. If I look at the source, the SRC points to the address of the reporting services server (of course, that's not public).

I'm sending the emails to public addresses like Yahoo and Gmail, so they cannot connect to the reporting services...

Any ideas how to fix this?

I just found this link: http://prndl.us/mhtml-html-decoding-c-sharp/
I used that code to change MHTML to html. If I save the string as local file with html extension and double click it, I can see the picture. But if I send same string as email body, still the picture doesn't show...

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure: I wrote the code at http://prndl.us/mhtml-html-decoding-c-sharp/

The code there can base64 encode the image and embed it as an image with a data uri. Some email clients don't like this (a lot of email clients have archaic html rendering engines). You can choose to not base64 encode the image and instead save it to a server or database and then insert the link to the image in the html.

We have done this with the code you saw in order to do exactly what you want to do.